# Regex separate ports by comma

Tags: php, regex, validation

**Problem**

I have a working port validity checker, however I need to separate the ports by a comma (no spaces). For instance instead of just '80' being valid, now '80,443,8080' would be valid.

**Regex**

```
(^(?:6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[0-9])$
```

**Tried**

I realise that I may need to break the query up, so tried many things including appending this (,\n|,?$) to the end of the query, however this did not work.

Comment: If a regex gets that long, it might be a better idea to refactor it into other string manipulation and clearer regexes, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is PHP, with PCRE regex flavor, you can easily recurse the subpattern  with a subroutine:

```
^(6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[0-9])(?:,(?1))*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kF6cM6/1)

*Explanation*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[0-9])` - Group 1: the single port validation subpattern
- `(?:,(?1))*` - 0+ sequences of `,` followed with the subpattern above (with the `(?1)` subroutine that re-uses the pattern inside the Group 1)
- `$` - end of string

Comment: I've modified the regex demo to allow ports separated by dash and comma at the same time, so you must validate if the ports are in the format 80-81 or 80,81,82

https://regex101.com/r/kF6cM6/8

Answer (score 0):

Other way, you can negate what you are looking for. This means:

- 5 digits numbers upper to 65535, or at least 6 digit numbers
- contiguous commas, or commas at the end or beginning of the string
- characters that are not a digit or a comma

To use this kind of pattern, you obviously need to negate the `preg_match` function:

```
return !preg_match('~6(?:5(?:5(?:3(?:[6-9]|\d{2})|[4-9]\d)|[6-9]\d{2})|[6-9]\d{3})|[7-9]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{5}|\B,|,\B|[^\d,]~S', $str);
```

The S modifier switches on the optimization for non-anchored patterns.

This approach can be interesting since the search stops as soon as the pattern succeeds.